# Creating JButtons in loop causes only last one to appear

Tags: java, loops, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to read a file with a scanner and create a JButton for each new line in the file. After I create a button, I add it to the frame. However once I run the program, only the most recent button appears. I'm not sure why creating the buttons in a loop causes this to happen. If anyone has an explanation for why this happens, that would be very much appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PointOfSale extends JFrame {

    ArrayList<JButton> menuButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    public PointOfSale(File menu) throws IOException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(menu);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            JButton menuButton = new JButton(name);
            frame.add(menuButton);
            menuButtons.add(menuButton);
        }
        sc.close();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You sure that there are only one button ? Check their positions.

Comment: I can only see one button, yes. Maybe they are overlapping?

Comment: Why are you extending the JFrame if you are also creating it? You are effectively calling `frame.add(menuButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);` on every one. You need to change `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` to `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

Comment: they are being covered. question closed.

Comment: reopened the question by mistake since I missed all the secondary points of the primary answer. Reclosed (using the link provided by hovvercraft) since it does answer the question, although not directly.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you! I figured I was screwing up the layout somehow...

Comment: I don't think this is the right duplicate though, as he was setting the Layout to FlowLayout, just on the wrong Object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not respect layout managers as the JFrame uses a BorderLayout which will only display one button. Read the layout manager tutorials, use different ones, here perhaps a GridLayout, and you'll likely have your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
//public class PointOfSale extends JFrame {
public class PointOfSale {
```

There is no need for your class to extend JFrame since you create the JFrame in the class.

Then you need to use:

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

since this is the frame you add the buttons to.